# Xcode 7 creates much larger binaries

Tags: xcode7

I did my first archives with Xcode 7 GM seed and my apps are 2x to 6x larger without making any changes from Xcode 6.  They are all Objective-C apps.  Any ideas why the binaries are so much larger in Xcode 7?

Comment: just a guess: does it contain a 32 and a 64 variant of your code ?

Comment: I have arm64, armv7 and armv7s.

Comment: Did xcode6 support these 3 architectures too ? If not this might be the cause of the increase in xcode7

Comment: I don't remember but one binary jumped 6x in size which is too much for that to be the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause.  It's the new "Enable Bitcode" option in build settings under build options in Xcode 7.  It's turned on by default.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html